# No route matches [GET]. Trying to [PUT]. Rake routes shows this path with put and patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**routes.rb**

```
  namespace :scheduling do
      resources :scheduling_details, only: [:create, :destroy, :update, :index]
    do
```

**rake routes**

```
scheduling_scheduling_detail 
PATCH  /scheduling/scheduling_details/:id(.:format)
scheduling/scheduling_details#update
PUT    /scheduling/scheduling_details/:id(.:format) 
scheduling/scheduling_details#update
```

**view**

```
<%= link_to "Yes", scheduling_scheduling_detail_path(@scheduling_detail) %>
```

**Error**. No route matches [GET] "/scheduling/scheduling_details/6256"

Notice the plural there.  I'm not sure why it's trying to access the plural url when I didn't use the plural path shortcut.

So I try to use the manual url instead of the path shortcut

```
<%= link_to "Yes", "/scheduling/scheduling_detail/#{@scheduling_detail}" %>
```

**Error:** No route matches [GET] "/scheduling/scheduling_detail"

Maybe try with the id?

```
<%= link_to "Yes", "/scheduling/scheduling_detail/#{@scheduling_detail.id}" %>
```

**Error:** No route matches [GET] "/scheduling/scheduling_detail/6256"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `:show` to your array, like so:

```rb
 namespace :scheduling do
      resources :scheduling_details, only: [:create, :destroy, :update, :index, :show]
    do
```

And make sure you have a show method in your controller and a view.

Comment: I purposely left out the :show action because there is never a need to show one member of this model.  I'm trying update/put.

Comment: Oh gotcha. I'm pretty sure the `link_to` method only renders anchor tags and they are only a GET method by default.

I think you want to render a submit button with a form instead that has a PUT action.

Comment: This was the solution that ended up working for me: Using a "button_to" instead of a "link_to".  I'm happy to mark your answer as the correct one if you add that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per your routes printout:
Your paths are plural. The issue is that you don’t have a GET method, which corresponds to the show view.

You’ll want to change your link_to method to PUT or PATCH.

Something like this in your view should work:

```
<%= link_to "Yes", scheduling_scheduling_detail_path(@scheduling_detail), method: :put %>
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the wrong path using `scheduling_scheduling_detail` you are specifying the `#GET` Request you need to use the `update_` prefix to specify `PUT/PATCH`. The following would do the trick.

```
<%= link_to "Yes", update_scheduling_scheduling_detail_path(@scheduling_detail) %>
```